Bishops reasoning regarding change of variables?

I'm a little confused by Bishop's reasoning here. If I've understood correctly, and correct me if I'm wrong, he's saying:

For an arbitrarily small change ${\delta y}$ of $y$, let ${\delta x}$ be the corresponding change in $x$ (we are assuming ${x = g(y)}$ for some function $g$, which I would guess we are assuming is nice and smooth etc). Then, the probability of observing $X$ in ${[x, x+\delta x]}$ should be equal to the probability of observing $Y$ in ${[y,y + \delta y]}$.
As long as ${\delta y}$ is small enough, these can be approximated asymptotically by ${p_Y(y)|\delta y|}$, ${p_X(x) |\delta x|}$.
Hence, ${p_Y(y) \sim p_X(x)\left|\frac{\delta x}{\delta y}\right|}$, and so in the limit as ${\delta y \to 0}$ we get ${p_Y(y) = p_X(g(y))|g'(y)|}$.

My issue with this is: in order to state

The probability of observing $X$ in ${[x, x+\delta x]}$ should be equal to the probability of observing $Y$ in ${[y,y + \delta y]}$

don't we need to assume $g$ is injective? Am I being dumb?

Yes, this description is implicitly assuming the function $g(y)$ is differentiable and injective (such as being differentiable and strictly increasing, or differentiable and strictly  decreasing).
In general, if $Y$ has a PDF $f_Y(y)$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and $X=g(Y)$, and if $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is a point with $k$ values $y_1, ..., y_k$ that satisfy $x=g(y_i)$, and if $g'(y_i)\neq 0$ for all $i$, then
$$ f_X(x)|\Delta x| \approx \sum_{i=1}^k f_Y(y_i)|\Delta y_i|$$
so
$$ \boxed{f_X(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{f_Y(y_i)}{|g'(y_i)|}}$$
So if $Y$ has a PDF and $X=Y^2$, then for all $x>0$ we get
$$ f_X(x)=\frac{f_Y(-\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{f_Y(\sqrt{x})}{2\sqrt{x}} $$
where $y_1=-\sqrt{x}$ and $y_2=\sqrt{x}$. You can test this, for example, for $Y\sim \mbox{Unif}[-1,1]$:
$$ f_Y(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
1/2 & \mbox{if $-1\leq y \leq 1$} \\
0 & \mbox{else} 
\end{array}\right.$$
to get a PDF for $X=Y^2$ that indeed integrates to 1.

That makes a lot of sense, thank you! I'm happy to see I wasn't going crazy haha
